# Why is there a random space in this JSX?

Tags: reactjs

I have this JSX rendering:

```
<AverageCostDescription>
  Results ranged from <AverageCost>{measureName ? `${currency}${tradMin} - ${currency}${tradMax}` : `${currency}${flexMin} - ${currency}${flexMax}`}.</AverageCost> The average is calculated from running five thousand simulations.
</AverageCostDescription>
```

My question is why is there a seemingly a random space in between the last number and the period? See this image:

[image]

Going into dev tools also show that it's a space:

[image]

But I don't think I left any room for a space in my JSX? I'm not sure if this is a CSS issue neither seeing as my `span` only has `font-weight: 600` attached. Could it be how React just renders this?

Comment: `console.log(tradMin)` & `console.log(flexMin)`

Comment: @kinduser Wow... I guess I trusted the variables too much as I didn't think to even look at it. It has an extra space. thank you